# Can I assign Permission set to a profile instead of user?

Tags: profile, user, permission-sets, user-record

I knew that Permission set can be assigned to User record. But just want to know the possibility of assigning the Permission set to a Profile instead of user.

I saw some query related to this posted on 2013 [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18502/is-it-possible-to-assign-permission-sets-owned-by-profile), & Its mentioned in answer that saleforce will re-evaluate the current decision based on more requests for this. Anybody knew whether any change to this scenario or any comment on this.

Comment: Surely if the Permission Set was being assigned to a Profile then it would make more sense to actually just add those permissions within that Profile.

Comment: @DaveHumm Not if for example the permission set was part of a managed package and it changed with each release of the managed package (as new fields and features are added).

Comment: @KeithC - useful reminder as Managed Packages do mean there is quite a lot of additional permissions mangement to remember.

Comment: @DaveHumm - yes it's true that the Permission set assigned to Profile looks more cleaner than individual user records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can not able to assign Permission set to Profile. We need to assign it to a User only.

A permission set is a collection of settings and permissions that give users access to various tools and functions. The settings and permissions in permission sets are also found in profiles, but permission sets extend users’ functional access without changing their profiles.

Users can have only one profile but, depending on the Salesforce edition, they can have multiple permission sets. You can assign permission sets to various types of users, regardless of their profiles.

[Reference Link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=perm_sets_overview.htm)

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK the platform has no direct support for this.

But you can write workflow logic or trigger code to add/delete the `PermissionSetAssignment` objects automatically based on attributes of the `User` including the `Profile` or custom fields that you add. The relevant part of the data model is included below (from the [Profile and Permission Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_profile_permissions.htm) documentation).

[image: Profile and Permission Objects]

Obviously only worth doing if you have a lot of users whose setup you want to manage systematically.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a permission set, you can opt to have it auto-assigned whenever another specific permission set is assigned. For instance, let's say you a Permission Set for a managed package, which you can't edit because it is controlled by the managed package. However, you also have custom fields that you want to make available to everyone who has the managed package permission set. When you create your own Permission Set, choose the associated managed package permission set in the License drop-down.

This doesn't solve the limitation of assigning by profile, but it can make it easier to keep managed and custom permission sets in sync for users.

Meanwhile, I will also try the workflow to assign based on user attributes.

Answer (score 1):

According to a recent response by Salesforce on this [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdikSUAR/assign-a-permission-set-to-a-profile), there is a possibility that this feature will be made available within the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add Permission Sets to profile, but you can use a work around.

Create a corresponding Permission Set Group for each Profile. Then always add Users to the Profile AND the Permission Set Group.

Then you can add Permission Sets to the Permission Set Group, and all users in the group will receive the permission set.